# React: default props error

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error:

```
Unexpected token (14:21)
  12 | class MeetingMap extends React.Component {
  13 |
> 14 |     static propTypes = {
     |                      ^
  15 |         accountId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  16 |     };
  17 |
```

Here is code:

```
static propTypes = {
    account: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

static defaultProps = {
    account: ''
};
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: do you transpile your code to ES7?

Comment: I did it like this and it works `MeetingMap.defaultProps = { account: '' }`, positioned below class and then exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/203) related to your question, class properties are a stage 0 proposal for ES7. If you would like to use this feature, you'll need the [Babel stage 0 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/). Otherwise, you'll need to use the default method of adding propTypes, as shown in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Counter.propTypes = { initialCount: PropTypes.number };
Counter.defaultProps = { initialCount: 0 };

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. If I use stage 0 for ES7, I could use propTypes and defaultProps as static property of class?

Comment: Yes. You can use the preset, or the transform directly. http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/